# How to combine multiple rows depending on factor level?

Tags: r

i hope that i can describe my question specifically enough. I have a very large dataframe in R. In this dataframe i sometimes have one row for one person and other times i have two rows for one person. Now i want to combine the rows if the persons are identic (have the same factor Level on the person factor). However, all of my variables except two are identical if the factor Level is the same. The two variables that are not identical are factors and in need the Information from both rows so the second row should be listed as a new column for the first row.

I hope anybody can help me, thank you very much. I am sorry if the Problem is not clear I am happy to answer further questions.

This is what my data looks like, except that the dataframe is much bigger:

```
  zz <- "Person Address Happening Date Job
     John         abc Birth         22/03/1940        IT
     John         abc   Death       22/10/2018        IT         
      Sarah        cde      Birth    10/07/1930        Teacher
      Sarah        cde     Death     01/07/2000        Teacher
      Susi         bfg     Birth     01/01/1990       secretary"
Data <- read.table(text=zz, header = TRUE)
```

You can see, that some persons appear twice because they have a date of death, those People that are still alive obviously appear only once. On the long run, I want to calculate an age span and construct a new factor, that says if the People are still alive or not.

All I could find were codes like this:

```
mtcars %>%
group_by(cyl) %>%
summarise(disp = mean(disp), sd = sd(disp))
```

However, the Problem is, that I cannot really summaries the variables as they are either factors or I want to calculate a difference between them.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you want the people to help you, you should provide a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), or use the `dput()` and `head()` function to have a piece of your data to give, in order them to give you an answer.

Comment: I am sorry I hope it is a little bit clearer now. Since my dataframe is really big and contains sensitive data I cannot really give a Piece of it but I have tried to create an example that Shows my Problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to convert data in long format into wide format. You can do this using the `spread()` function:

```r
library(tidyverse)
zz <- "Person Address Happening Date Job
     John         abc Birth         22/03/1940        IT
     John         abc   Death       22/10/2018        IT         
      Sarah        cde      Birth    10/07/1930        Teacher
      Sarah        cde     Death     01/07/2000        Teacher
      Susi         bfg     Birth     01/01/1990       secretary"
Data <- read.table(text=zz, header = TRUE)
Data
#>   Person Address Happening       Date       Job
#> 1   John     abc     Birth 22/03/1940        IT
#> 2   John     abc     Death 22/10/2018        IT
#> 3  Sarah     cde     Birth 10/07/1930   Teacher
#> 4  Sarah     cde     Death 01/07/2000   Teacher
#> 5   Susi     bfg     Birth 01/01/1990 secretary

spread(Data, Happening, Date)
#>   Person Address       Job      Birth      Death
#> 1   John     abc        IT 22/03/1940 22/10/2018
#> 2  Sarah     cde   Teacher 10/07/1930 01/07/2000
#> 3   Susi     bfg secretary 01/01/1990       <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2018-11-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: That is exactly what I was tryong to do! Thank you so much!